# how to print "box drawers"?

Tags: java, android, character

In the old days I could print single and double lined boxes using characters.
I would do such thing in java for android, just in the logging.
But, I realy can't find those chars.

There are a few who come close to what I need, (char) 741, 743, 745, 746, 747
915, 1994, 2027.

I could create a new android activity and use linedraw, but that not what I would like to use in this case.. its just for use in the logging and printing a box/menu like with the old dos-characters.
 theire number then where , decimal, 179 to 218

thank for your attention and time.

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: Yep Mike, thats what I mean. I realize I would have asked for how to use the old DOS-Graphic characters. I bed it no longer possible. even on my Linux-terminal it is not possible. Which i just found out.. very sad.

Comment: Why can't you just use the Unicode characters?

Comment: Thats what I do/ did. but is not as nice as the old dos graphic characters.  As because of this I made a second activity to draw / visualise the situation.  It works fine for me, although was not what I wished for. How can I now mark this as completed.